# Hide the "resizing" handle in a resizable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resizable

There are a few other questions which are similar, but none works or seems in the right area.  I'm trying to make a table's columns' widths resizable. My table is a normal HTML `table`, except that it has the Bootstrap 4 class `table` (maybe they could have thought of a different name...!).

My css looks like this:

```
.resizable-div {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:block;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

The relevant bit of JS where I add the cell to the table row with a resizable div inside it, and text inside that, is like this:

```
row.appendChild(cell);
const resizableTdDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
resizableTdDiv.classList.add( 'resizable-div');
cell.appendChild( resizableTdDiv );
const cellTextNode = document.createTextNode(isHeader ? fieldName : value);
resizableTdDiv.appendChild(cellTextNode);
```

The result works fine: resizable columns. Hurrah. There is only one fly in the ointment:

[image]

I can get rid of the borders, of course. I just want to lose those pesky handler triangles in the bottom right corners... all of them!

I realise users have to be given an idea that they are able to resize the columns... but I'd be perfectly happy to do that some other way if I could replace those triangle icons with 100% transparent ones (for example).

**Edit**

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5matrnke/)! Amazingly easy to do!

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: There isn't any really, just a `body` with a plain `div` under it... the `table` is put under that entirely by JS means. I've never done a JSFiddle before and I don't know how they work. I'd be willing to try, but in this case I suspect that this wouldn't actually enlighten anyone much: anyone trying this technique would presumably find this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in WebKit based browsers currently with the `::-webkit-resizer` pseudo element.

```css
div{
overflow:auto;
resize:both;
width:50%;
}

div:nth-of-type(2)::-webkit-resizer{
background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
Not Hidden
</div>

<div>
Hidden
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my browser (FF 72) both divs in your snippet have the triangle... Aha, but in Chrome  (79), yes, the second one is hidden. I'm pretty committed to FF myself.

Comment: Yes, FF is not a webkit browser

Answer (score 0):

WebKit provides a pseudo-element for this `::-webkit-resizer` and you can hide those triangles by applying `display: none`, `-webkit-appearance: none`, or `background: transparent`.

For Firefox or anything without WebKit an alternative / workaround would be to position a custom handle over top of each resizable div. This may require some different markup though.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resizable-div {
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:block;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.handle {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* ::-webkit-resizer {
    background: transparent;
} */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="resizable-div"></div>
  <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```